# Adding a cell value to a formula within a COUNTIFS

Tags: google-sheets, cell, countif

I have this formula working;

```
=COUNTIFS($G$14:G,"Submitted",C14:C, "=28")
```

The number 28 is given from cell B1 - how do I make 28 reference 'B1' & work.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTIFS($G$14:G, "Submitted", C14:C, B1)
```